# Route Planning with Set of Ordered Waypoint Pairs

Tags: algorithm, sorting, optimization, shortest-path

I have a set of nodes. Travel cost from one node to a connected node is always 1, but not all nodes are connected directly. That is to say, travel from node A to C may required passing through node B, and it's total travel cost would be 2.

I then have a set of ordered pair waypoints. Each waypoint pair contains an origin node and destination node, which must be visited in order.

The ordered pairs themselves do not have to be visited in any particular order, nor must the destination node be visited immediately following the origin node.

A node may be visited twice, if that were to optimize the overall route. It should never need to visited thrice.

How can I order my nodes to achieve a minimum travel cost and ensure all nodes contained in a waypoint are visited, and adhere to the ordered pair rule above?

I'm banging my head against the wall with this.

Comment: what if your waypoints are (a,b) & (c,d) and the only route between (a,b) is (a,d,c,b) ? you'd be forced to go from d to c which is not allowed according to the requirements (source and destination not in order).

Comment: Then D must be revisited to satisfy the second pair of waypoints.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is an NP-Hard problem as it reduces from the (Metric) Traveling Salesman Problem.

This means that in the general case, it cannot be done in polynomial time. There are several approaches you can take

- Accept superpolynomial running times
- Relax the requirements, so it is no longer NP Complete
- Use an approximation algorithm
- Constrain your graphs to a set that can be solved efficiently (such as bounded branchwidth graphs)

Or you could use a combination of approaches. For example, use an exact algorithm that solves common cases quickly, and fall back to an approximation algorithm in pathological cases.

Comment: the question didn't ask for polynomial time...
also, although it certainly reminds TSP, are you sure it can be reduced to it ?

Comment: I am interested in a general solution to the problem at hand. If it is suboptimal, or operates in exponential time, that is OK. The graphs are not exceedingly large. Are you to say, though, that I must walk every possible route, checking for adherence to rules as i go, then compare them all eligible routes for shortest length?

Comment: *"This is NP-Hard .. as it reduces to TSP"* - I assume you mean reduces **from** TSP?  Reducing to TSP only shows that the problem is NP, which isn't saying much.

Comment: @BlueRaja, I meant that anything that can solve this problem can also solve TSP. I don't remember the exact terminology.

Answer (score 0):

not a complete answer, just thinking out loud, a sort of greedy approach:

1. compute the shortest distances matrix for the graph,
2. find the pair of waypoints for which the shortest route is the longest.
3. append that route to the final result.
4. remove any pair of waypoints that appears in that route from the set of waypoints that are yet to be handled.
5. repeat from 2 for the remaining waypoints until there are none left.

if you encounter a pair of waypoints which appear in a route in reverse order, need to come up with  an 'efficient' way to traverse the route in reverse as well.

another idea:

find the minimal spanning tree of the graph and traverse it left to right and right to left.